# Selecting entities that contain all the values inside the WHERE IN clause

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to display all the entities that have all the values i'm putting inside the WHERE IN so i've done this using HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;

```
SELECT d.semundjeName
FROM rel r JOIN
semundjet d
ON r.semundjeID = d.semundjeID
WHERE r.simptomaID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY d.semundjeName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;
```

and it works fine but i want to do the same, but with names, rather than ids, so i've done

```
select semundjeName
from simptomat 
left join rel
on rel.semundjeID = semundjet.semundjeID
left join semundjet
on semundjet.semundjeID = rel.semundjeID
where simptomaName IN ('Merzi','Dhimbje Koke','Gjakederdhje','Dhimbje 
Fyti','Dhimbje Kycesh')
group by semundjeName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;
```

and it doesn't seem to work. Can I do the same without using HAVING COUNT(*) at all? Meaning, to display only the entities that contain all the values inside WHERE IN all the time.

```
#semundjet - holds all disease names
######################################
semundjeID | semundjeName     
-----------------------
1            Malarja       
2            Epilepsi    
3            Depresion
4            Tuberkuloz
5            Kancer


#simptomat - holds all symptoms
#################################
simptomaID | simptomaName
------------------------- 
1            Merzi       
2            Dhimbje Koke    
3            Gjakederdhje
4            Dhimbje Fyti
5            Dhimbje Kycesh


 #rel - holds relation between diseases and symptoms
 ######################################################
 relID  | semundjeID | simptomaID
 -----------------------------
 1         1          1
 2         1          2
 3         3          1
 4         3          2
 5         3          3
 6         4          4
 7         5          5
 8         5          1
 9         5          2
 10        5          3
 11        5          4
```

The expected output would be "Kancer" since it is the only entity that contains all the symptoms "simptomaID", And i can get that output from the first query, but not from the second one.

*It'd be favorable if there was a way to do it without using Having Count(*) = 5; at all, but automatically return as output the entity that contains **all** the values in the IN condition*

Comment: add table schema and expected output

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select semundjeName
from simptomat 
left join rel
on rel.semundjeID = simptomat.simptomaID
left join semundjet
on semundjet.semundjeID = rel.semundjeID
where simptomaName IN ('Merzi','Dhimbje Koke','Gjakederdhje','Dhimbje 
Fyti','Dhimbje Kycesh')
group by semundjeName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5;
```

and put all filter `simptomaName` into a table to avoid `=5`

```
select semundjeName
from simptomat 
left join rel
on rel.semundjeID = simptomat.simptomaID
left join semundjet
on semundjet.semundjeID = rel.semundjeID
where simptomaName IN (select 'Merzi'
union select 'Dhimbje Koke'
union select 'Gjakederdhje'
union select 'Dhimbje Fyti'
union select 'Dhimbje Kycesh')
group by semundjeName
HAVING COUNT(*) = (select count(*) from (select 'Merzi'
union select 'Dhimbje Koke'
union select 'Gjakederdhje'
union select 'Dhimbje Fyti'
union select 'Dhimbje Kycesh') a);
```

just dynamically create a temp table or generate text like

```
select 'Merzi'
union select 'Dhimbje Koke'
union select 'Gjakederdhje'
union select 'Dhimbje Fyti'
union select 'Dhimbje Kycesh')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT simptomaName) = 5
```

because this is what you want to count, right?

Comment: I want to display the entity that contains all the values inside of IN condition. For example "kancer" (see table) since it contains all the values inside of IN. But not display all the other entities which contain only some of the values inside on IN.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT simptomaName)` counts all the distinct values of `simptomaName`. Since you have in  WHERE exactly 5 values of `simptomaName`, then you will get all the entities that have all these 5 values.

Comment: That works fine too, thanks, but I see now my problem was elsewhere in the query, thank you lot anyway.